# ChromeOption '--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection' doesn't disables the download warning in Chrome version 67.x

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to use Selenium webdriver to automate some of the work. My automation includes downloading some .msg outlook email file from the web attached by somebody else. Downloading the .msg file prompted a warning from Chrome saying "This type of file can harm the computer...". Using the ChromeOptions to add argument --safebrowsing-disable-download-protection does not work, the download still prompted the warning with the argument added into the chrome options, any help will be appreciated.

Code trial:

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

printing the `chrome_options.arguments` shows that the `'--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection'` is added into the arguments, but when I started to download the .msg files using Selenium, I still receive the same warning.

Something to note, when i manually run chrome.exe via cmd using the '--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection', downloading without warning works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
  "download.default_directory": r"C:\Users\downloads",
  "download.prompt_for_download": False,
  "download.directory_upgrade": True,
  "safebrowsing.enabled": False
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: I've tried safebrowsing.enabled: True added into experimental_option but still to no avail..

Comment: Did you try the whole code snippet I have provided?

Comment: Tried your snippet, suprisingly, the warning still exist, but the file downloaded successfully.

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry. `safebrowsing.enabled` should be of cource `False`. I have edited my code, please try it.

Answer (score 1):

As per your *code trials* as you are trying to implement **`--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection`** through `ChromeOptions()` but it is worth to mention the following points:

- As per [**Remove kSbDisableDownloadProtection flag to make download safebrowsing protect a default behavior**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=74848) **`--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection`** is supposed to be cleaned up as a command flag to make *download safebrowsing protect* a default behavior.
- The [fix](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/ba49d00fddeb39c0816090dad7d359df0dce9a1a) was dependent on [**Replace safe browsing DB and update protocol with Pver4**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543161) which was marked as **fixed** as no issues have been reported since full launch.
- Subsequently [**Remove kSbDisableDownloadProtection flag to make download safebrowsing protect a default behavior**](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=74848) was also marked as fixed.
- The fix [Enable PVer4 by default for desktop platforms](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/550e314e8fc7546b77de5beacb7654b838886915) establishes the fact that the *ChromeOption* **`--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection`** is no more effective.

### Conclusion

As per the points mentioned above the *ChromeOption* **`--safebrowsing-disable-download-protection`** is no more an effective/valid *ChromeOption* and should be handled by **PVer4** by default for desktop platforms.

Comment: Not quite understand on the link given. Care to eleborate more?

Comment: What is PVer4 and what I need to do to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromeDriver, options=options)
    params = {'behavior' : 'allow', 'downloadPath':r"C:\Users\downloads"}
    driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.setDownloadBehavior', params)
```